# Unix Solaris 5.11

Tags: bash, solaris

Buen dia.

Tengo una pregunta para lo siguiente.

Acabo de crear un script algo sencillo en el cual se hace un rsync para un respaldo en varios servidores de producción desde un servidor de pruebas es algo como lo siguiente

```
rsync -av /directorio/de/origen usuario1@xx.xx.xx.10:/directorio/de/destino

rsync -av /directorio/de/origen usuario1@xx.xx.xx.11:/directorio/de/destino

rsync -av /directorio/de/origen usuario1@xx.xx.xx.12:/directorio/de/destino
```

Sin embargo al ejecutar el script si hace el respaldo solo que en cada uno de los servidores me pide la contraseña

Hay alguna manera de autenticar cada servidor en el script con la contraseña sin que me la este pidiendo en cada servidor?
la contraseña y el usuario son las mismas para cada uno.

Espero que me puedan asistir con mi situacion.

Comment: Fíjate si acepta la opción --password-file nombre-archivo-que-contiene-password o variable de entorno RSYNC_PASSWORD

Comment: Lo que pasa es que los archivos no están encriptados lo que esta encriptado es el acceso al servidor y al momento de ingresar al servidor y tomar los archivos me pide la contraseña del servidor no de los archivos

Comment: La opción --password-file es para indicarle el archivo que contiene el password del servidor al que accedes.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por responder a mis dudas, que tengan buen dia!!